# How can I remove the ACL of PIX firewall?

Tags: firewall, access-control-list, cisco-pix

I'm just trying to how PIX works. Anyway how can I remove the ACL from my GNS3's PIX?

PIX-SECU(config)# show access-list
access-list cached ACL log flows: total 0, denied 0 (deny-flow-max 4096)
            alert-interval 300
access-list 1; 1 elements
**access-list 1 line 1 standard deny host 10.10.10.10 (hitcnt=0) 0x829743dd**
PIX-SECU(config)#

Also It works as a router mode. Thank you everybody.
Please understand me. I can't speak english very much.

Bye.

Comment: Please read a bit a the documentation... In configure mode, you just have to type "no <.. the line you want to remove ..>", it works for most of the configuration. But you need to read the doc and learn about the device if you want to manage it properly.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, Long time ago I did that with "no". But That command didn't get through. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface the undesired line from the **running config** with 'no' to delete it.

Eg. no access-list 1 standard deny host 10.10.10.10

Note: you need to delete the relevant line as it appears in the "running configuration", not the output of a command like "show access-list" as this includes things like the hit-count which aren't actually part of the config.

If you want to clear a WHOLE access list, then I believe you can use "clear config access-list 1"